# How to analyze differences of two groups with replicates?

Tags: r, anova, interpretation, group-differences

I am trying to see if there are differences between two groups (background genetic mutants) and some values associated to them. Every group has 4 different gene types with two replicates each and its respective value.

```
> data
bg              type     value
a            3motif 0.7371446
a            3motif 0.7519591
a     captured_exon 0.8030102
a     captured_exon 0.8110690
a  helicase_protein 0.7331316
a  helicase_protein 0.7479729
a replicase_protein 0.6897468
a replicase_protein 0.6967064
b            3motif 0.6934017
b            3motif 0.7076932
b     captured_exon 0.7725613
b     captured_exon 0.7816896
b  helicase_protein 0.6938436
b  helicase_protein 0.7153722
b replicase_protein 0.6630786
b replicase_protein 0.6831855
```

I'd first like to see if there are differences between the different types of each group (background). So, while looking for a possible answer I found that the following anova test would fit on my needs:

```
>aov(value~bg+Error(type), data = data)

Call:
    aov(formula = value ~ bg + Error(type), data = data)

Grand Mean: 0.7300979 

Stratum 1: type

Terms:
                 Residuals
Sum of Squares  0.02462776
Deg. of Freedom          3

Residual standard error: 0.09060494 

Stratum 2: Within

Terms:
                         bg   Residuals
Sum of Squares  0.004222238 0.001159024
Deg. of Freedom           1          11

Residual standard error: 0.01026479 
Estimated effects are balanced
```

But I don't know how to iterpret the results, would you please help me?

Comment: Can you say a little more about what is confusing you? What part of the interpretation do you not get?

Comment: As I understand, these results would tell me if there are differences within the groups (backgrounds) and/or between them. But since I'm new in statistics I can't tell if there are differences by looking at the bunch of data I got after doing the test.

Comment: Try `summary(aov(value~bg+Error(type), data = data))`.